# How can I prove the following relation from tensor calculus?

Tags: vector-spaces, tensors, jacobian, kronecker-symbol, kronecker-delta

$\frac{\partial \bar{x}_{i}}{\partial x_{r}} \frac{\partial {x}_{r}}{\partial \bar{ x_{j}}} = \delta^i_j \quad (The \quad Kronecker \quad Delta) \quad \quad\quad $
$\rightarrow (  \text{In my attempt, I ran r over {1,2,3..,n}}) \rightarrow \frac{\partial \bar{x}_{i}}{\partial x_{1}} \frac{\partial {x}_{1}}{\partial \bar{ x_{j}}} + \frac{\partial \bar{x}_{i}}{\partial x_{2}} \frac{\partial {x}_{2}}{\partial \bar{ x_{j}}} + ...+ \frac{\partial \bar{x}_{i}}{\partial x_{n}} \frac{\partial {x}_{n}}{\partial \bar{ x_{j}}} =  \delta^i_j +  \delta^i_j + ... +\delta^i_j = n \delta^i_j \quad \quad \text{But I know that it can not be right.} $

Comment: just it is $$\frac{\partial \bar{x}_{i}}{\partial x_{1}} \frac{\partial {x}_{1}}{\partial \bar{ x_{j}}} + \frac{\partial \bar{x}_{i}}{\partial x_{2}} \frac{\partial {x}_{2}}{\partial \bar{ x_{j}}} + ...+ \frac{\partial \bar{x}_{i}}{\partial x_{n}} \frac{\partial {x}_{n}}{\partial \bar{ x_{j}}} =  \delta^i_j$$

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the chain rule backwards. $\frac{\partial \bar{x}_{i}}{\partial x_{r}} \frac{\partial {x}_{r}}{\partial \bar{ x_{j}}} = \frac{\partial \bar{x}_{i}}{\partial \bar{x}_j} =  \delta^i_j $

Comment: You seem to have forgotten the \bar in the denominator

Comment: Yes, that's a typo, I'll edit it right away

Comment: But, @PackSciences, when I run r over {1,2, .., n}, I get new terms that are equal one when i =j. Why they can't be represented by the kronecker delta?

Comment: It's not a sum.

Comment: @packSciences I am using the Albert Einstein's notation. Which  always an index means a sum.

Comment: I know what is the Einstein convention of tensor, I am just saying that you don't have to sum it here. It's just chain rule backwards, nothing more.